# WCF Client check if WCF Host is up and running?

Tags: .net, wcf

I have a wcf service host(console application) and client over netTCPBinding.
In my requirement host goes down and coming up frequently.my client should handle host down and check for host is up for every 1 min .when I am trying to understand and implement that i came across many solutions.
1. WS-Discovery
2. IsAlive in server
3. Ping method etc.
4. polling

```
private static bool IsConnectionUp()
        {
            _logClient = new LogClient();

                try
                {
                    _logClient.Open();
                    return true;
                }
                catch (FaultException exception)
                {
                    if (_logClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {

                        _logClient = new LogClient();
                    }
                    return false;
                }


        }

    Main()
    {
     while (IsConnectionUp()!=true)
                {
                    IsConnectionUp();
                }
    }
```

the above piece of code good way to do if not please suggest.

I want to poll continuously for host from client.which is the best method i can adopt.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The existing code leaks connections which is dangerous. You need to implement the WCF dispose pattern (which is not the normal pattern due to an API design error by the WCF team).

Opening a connection does not necessarily test for availability. I don't know what your binding does when opening. I suspect HTTP-based binding do nothing at all. I don't think it's possible to ask the underlying `HttpWebRequest` infrastructure to open a connection without making a request.

The best way to do this is to implement a test method (e.g. `void Ping() { }`). Use a short timeout and dispose resources.

The unthrottled loop is dangerous as well. This is basically a denial of service attack.